# filtering drop down menu using value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible in javascript to filter a drop down menu based on another field menu using only value attribute?

I mean, I have the following code, which is built by the django-framework :

```
<p><label for="id_country">Country :</label> <select id="id_region" name="region">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="1">USA</option>
<option value="2">France</option>
</select></p>
<p><label for="id_region">Region :</label> <select id="id_city" name="city">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="1">California</option>
<option value="2">New-York</option>
<option value="3">Oregon</option>
<option value="4">Tenessee</option>
<option value="5">Paris</option>
<option value="6">Bretagne</option>
...
```

And I have to filter the value but only using the number of the value but I want to do it properly. Can we write something like:

```
if(id_country == USA) 
    then:
        id_region_value between 1 and 4
if(id_country == France)
    then:
        id_region_value between 5 and 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to each second `select`

```
$("#id_region").change(function(){
    $("#id_city option[value!='']").hide();
    if($(this).val()==1){
        $("#id_city option").each(function(){
            if($(this).val() >=1 && 4>=$(this).val()){
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
    }
    if($(this).val()==2){
        $("#id_city option").each(function(){
            if($(this).val() >=5 && 6>=$(this).val()){
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lTasty/46xLzgqm/

Answer (score 1):

You could use global options like this:

```
var options = {
    'USA' : { 1 : 'California', 2 : 'New York', 3 : 'Oregon', 4 : 'Tenessee' },
    'France' : { 5 : 'Paris', 6 : 'Bretagne' }
};
```

It's much easier this way to keep adding regions.

And then you build the options everytime the `id_region` changes:

```js
var options = {
        'USA' : { 1 : 'California', 2 : 'New York', 3 : 'Oregon', 4 : 'Tenessee' },
        'France' : { 5 : 'Paris', 6 : 'Bretagne' }
    };

$('#id_region').on('change', function(){
        //clean optionList
        $('#id_city').empty();
        //build optionList
        var cities = options[$('#id_region option:selected').text()];
        for(var index in cities){
            $('<option value= "' + index + '">' + cities[index] + '</option>').appendTo('#id_city');
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><label for="id_country">Country :</label> <select id="id_region" name="region">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
<option value="1">USA</option>
<option value="2">France</option>
</select></p>
<p><label for="id_region">Region :</label> <select id="id_city" name="city">
```

Comment: It is an interesting approach to have a robust code but wouldn't it slow the loading of the page if I write all the cities and all the region of the world?

Comment: You should only add the cities you need. If you are going to add all the cities in the world, then you could request the cities of the selected country through AJAX. That way you only load what you need when you need it.